# Set a color to be considered as transparent while including eps files in latex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps

I have some .eps files whose background colors are white. I need to include these graphics in my latex file, and my latex file has a background color different from white. I am willing to have these .eps files in my latex document without their white background colors being shown, i.e. I want the white color to be considered as a transparent color. Is this possible without using other graphical software?

**Edit:**

To clarify my question a bit more, I'll give you an example. In the picture below, on the right hand side is my original picture (with extension .eps), and on the left hand side is my latex file. I have included the picture in my latex file using \includegraphics command. When I build my latex file, the picture appears like what is marked as A. But what I am looking for is to do something in order for the picture to appear as what is marked as B.

[image]

Comment: LaTeX doesn't act in any way on the included graphics file (apart from scaling and rotating). It has no possibility of acting on its color space, nor changing channels.

Comment: I have the exact same question as the OP and think that the figure is very illustrative. Please re-activate the question therefore and allow constructive answers!

Comment: The answer here is: depends on the picture. If the picture does not have a background,  there are no problems in including it. Otherwise, there are tools able to remove the background: GIMP is one of them. Just google "GIMP remove background": lot of tutorials will detail how to proceed.

Comment: I think the people who vote to close a question, are responsible for opening it again as soon as the stated criticism is obviated. And it is really unprofessional that some people are doing it to collect more reputation. It has been seven days since I edited the question and I don't think that the question is ambiguous any more, but it is still closed.